# WCF Web Service not working after IIS restart

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5

I have a web service running on IIS 7.5

Whenever I restart the IIS or the AppPool of the website this web service is running I am getting the error message below. Then I found out that, if I change the complilation version (either from 4.5 to 4.0 or if it is 4.0 to 4.5) and save the web.config file then it starts working regularly. This is really weird. Can anybody help me on this please.

web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="NetDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EFatura.csdl|res://*/EFatura.ssdl|res://*/EFatura.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=***********;initial catalog=*****;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=***************;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=NSEfatLib&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="NSEfatLib.NSEfatEntryPoint">
        <endpoint address="Cari" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="Cari" contract="NSEfatLib.ICari" />
        <endpoint address="Stok" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="Stok" contract="NSEfatLib.IStok" />
        <endpoint address="FaturaIslemler" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" name="FaturaIslemler" contract="NSEfatLib.IFaturaIslemler" />
        <endpoint address="DefterIslemler" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" name="DefterIslemler" contract="NSEfatLib.IDefterIslemler" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Error Message:

> The type 'NSEfatLib.NSEfatEntryPoint', provided as the Service
>   attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the
>   configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found.  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The type
>   'NSEfatLib.NSEfatEntryPoint', provided as the Service attribute value
>   in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The type 'NSEfatLib.NSEfatEntryPoint',
>   provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive,
>   or provided in the configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found.]
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String
>   constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +122516
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1451
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo
>   serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +76
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +901
>
> [ServiceActivationException: The service '/Service.svc' cannot be
>   activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception
>   message is: The type 'NSEfatLib.NSEfatEntryPoint', provided as the
>   Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in
>   the configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found..]    System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
>   +650220    System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +210733
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +282

Event Log Entry:

> System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/62476613 
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service
>   '/Service.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during
>   compilation. The exception message is: The type
>   'NSEfatLib.NSEfatEntryPoint', provided as the Service attribute value
>   in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found.. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type
>   'NSEfatLib.NSEfatEntryPoint', provided as the Service attribute value
>   in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found. at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String
>   constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo
>   serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) --- End
>   of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String
>   relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)     w3wp
>   5028

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly above error was fired when the web service was precompiled. I tried the service to run regularly (without precomopiling) and the issue is not appearing anymore.

I was using a library within the web service, so practically the web service itself did not have any code at all. Maybe that is the reason. Anyways, as there is no code, no precompilation is fine too.