# the type '*', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element * could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, azure

I have a provider hosted app in sharepoint which works locally without problem. I followed this tutorial to publish it to azure

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/09/05/how-to-deploy-a-provider-hosted-app-as-an-azure-site.aspx

However after publishing the webservice doesnt work I get this exception:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The type 'x.IntranetWeb.Services.AppEventReceiver', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.]
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +62739
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1429
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +52
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +598

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/Services/AppEventReceiver.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The type 'x.IntranetWeb.Services.AppEventReceiver', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +486572
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +174
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult ar) +345998
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +9683593
```

My web.config which I didnt touch.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientId" value="xx-04e7-4caf-854a-89c20577d7da" />
    <add key="ClientSecret" value="ljguTvxHR+xx+Pl1IMg1Hjt5rsQ=" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <!--Used by app for SharePoint-->
        <binding name="secureBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="secureBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and a piece of the code of the remote event receiver

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="x.IntranetWeb.Services.AppEventReceiver" CodeBehind="AppEventReceiver.svc.cs" %>


namespace x.IntranetWeb.Services
{
    public class AppEventReceiver : IRemoteEventService
    {
```

and the global.asax, as this is an MVC application with a .svc on it, maybe it has something to do with routing?

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you try , removing `handlers` part from config, deploy to azure!, then let me know, if that helps. And make sure you have `AppEventReceiver` class in code behind file, i.e. `AppEventReceiver.svc.cs`.

Comment: Make sure that assembly in which type "x.IntranetWeb.Services.AppEventReceiver" resides is presents there in bin directory and bin directory should be at same level as that of your .svc file.

Comment: interesting, actually there is a folder called Services with AppEventReceiver, so its not at the same level of the bin folder, any reason why this works locally and not on azure?

Comment: @ArindamNayak removing the handlers part didnt make any difference

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your service class name, it should be the same in *.svc markup file "Service = ..."

For example:

```
namespace my{

     public class DummyService: IWebService
     {
        //implementation
     }
}
```

*.svc markup: <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="**my.DummyService**" CodeBehind="myservice.svc.cs" %>

2. Try to check this:
   [WCF Web Service not working after IIS restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931366/wcf-web-service-not-working-after-iis-restart)

"Interestingly above error was fired when the web service was precompiled. I tried the service to run regularly (without precomopiling) and the issue is not appearing anymore.

I was using a library within the web service, so practically the web service itself did not have any code at all. Maybe that is the reason. Anyways, as there is no code, no precompilation is fine too"

3. Can you ckeck application pool for your service? Is it started?

Comment: please check the code I pasted, its the same, and it works locally, can you explain why it works locally but not in azure??

Comment: Nr 1 is correct, Nr 2 and 3 I have no control because hosting its in windows azure.

Comment: Try to create default WCF service with default web.config and publish it on azure.

Comment: how to I make it not precompiled??